Does the bonus damage to undead stack if wielding multiple divine weapons?
If you collect enough silver coins, you can have the weaponsmith melt them down and craft the resulting silver ingots into sterling/righteousness/divine weapons, which grant a +15% damage buff against undead mobs. For almost all classes, it's really only viable to equip one of these weapons at a time, since they are either two handed or primary weapons. However, a short sword is one of the craftable weapons, and since that's a secondary weapon, you could potentially dual wield that with another divine primary weapon. I was thinking a slayer fighter using a divine rondel dagger with a divine short sword could work. Does the undead damage bonus stack from using both weapons? Does that mean you'd get a +30% damage boost against undead?
